# Reference parameter (&) with and without const in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

So I was writing a program yesterday, and I encountered a problem that when I use a reference without `const`, it'll be an error whenever I tried to call that function later. For example:

```
bool is_vowel(const string& s) //OK;
bool is_vowel(string& s) //Error!
{
    if (s == "A" || s == "a") return true;
    if (s == "E" || s == "e") return true;
    if (s == "I" || s == "i") return true;
    if (s == "O" || s == "o") return true;
    if (s == "U" || s == "u") return true;
    if (s == "Y" || s == "y") return true;

    return false;
}
```

And considering the following that calls this function: (for simplicity, I've cut out a huge chunk of the original code, so don't focus on the logic here)

```
int FRI_Syllables(const string& s)
{
    int syllables = 0;

    for (int n = 0; n < s.length(); n++)
        if (is_vowel(s.substr(n, 1)))
            syllables ++;
}

return syllables;
```

}

So when I use this function, the line that calls `is_vowel` when I don't use `const` will return a compile-time error saying "No matching function for call to 'is_vowel'".

I know why references with `const` here works; what I don't understand is why the one without doesn't.

And another thing that makes me more confusing is that in the `FRI_Syllables` function, the references work with AND without the `const`. So considering a part of the code in the main function that calls this function:

```
int main()
{
    //rest of the code

    int syllables = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
        syllables += FRI_Syllables(words[i]);

    //rest of the code
}
```

This won't return any error whether I use `int FRI_Syllables(const string& s)` or `int FRI_Syllables(string& s)`. So why the differences? Why would references without `const` sometimes work and others don't?

Comment: Why pass a whole string to is_vowel when you could pass a single character? Perhaps it was just for an example?

Comment: I did intend to use `char` instead of `string`, if that's what you mean. I just use string for a little bit of consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-const lvalue reference variable only binds to lvalues, not to rvalues. By contrast, a *const* lvalue reference binds to both lvalues and rvalues.

Since the result of `s.substr(n, 1)` is an rvalue (a "temporary value"), it cannot bind to a non-constant lvalue reference.

The reasoning behind this language design choice is that the purpose of a non-constant lvalue reference is to allow you to *change* the object that's being referred to, but when that object is temporary, the changes would be lost immediately, so this is basically never what you could have intended.

Comment: I see. So based on your explanation, is it correct that the `main` function works even when the `FRI_Syllables` function is not `const` because `words[i]` is a lvalue (not "temporary") so it can bind with a non-const lvalue?

Comment: Just as a C++ beginner myself, one of my "aha" moments came the other day when I realized that "lvalue" and "rvalue" (probably) refer to the left- and right-hand sides of an assignment expression. Lvalues can be assigned to; rvalues can't. Might've been obvious but the texts I read never made that explicit and it took me a while to make the connection.

Comment: @dmau1982: Yes, that's the origin of the name, though it's more of a mnemonic now than an actual, precise term. By the way, in C there are only "lvalues" and things that are "not an lvalue". The term "rvalue" (and "xvalue") seems to have been invented for C++.